# MySQL Windows c api named pipes ERROR: "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'Waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: c++, windows, api, mysql

I am writing a c++ program that will store everything in a mysql database.  I would like to avoid the Windows Security window from popping up and asking if mysqld can have priviledges.  If I click cancel (in response to the firewall window), the program still runs just fine because everything is local.

I am trying to use named pipes with the --skip-networking flag to avoid this firewall window.

START EDIT:

I am using a portable version of mysqld.  It won't have admin priviledges.  (Thanks to Ben for pointing out that this is an important piece of information)

END EDIT

I am using the following command to start the mysqld server:

```
C:\tmp_report\12345\mysqld\mysql\bin\mysqld --user=root \
--basedir="C:\tmp_report\12345\mysqld\\mysql" \
--datadir="C:\tmp_report\12345\mysqld\data" \
--pid-file="C:\tmp_report\12345\mysqld\mysql.pid" \
--log-error="C:\tmp_report\12345\mysqld\mysql.err" \
--skip-networking \
--enable-named-pipe
```

This works and I am able to connect to the database using the following command line statement:

```
mysql --pipe -uroot
```

I am trying to connect through the c-api as follows:

```
unsigned int mysql_timeout=200;
unsigned int protocol=MYSQL_PROTOCOL_PIPE;
bool mysql_reconnect=true;
bool mysql_local_infile=true;

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, (char *)&mysql_timeout)){*logstream<<"mysql option error connect_timeout";}

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT, (char *)&mysql_timeout)){*logstream<<"mysql option error read_timeout";}

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT, (char *)&mysql_timeout)){*logstream<<"mysql option error write_timeout";}

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT,                   &mysql_reconnect)){*logstream<<"mysql option error reconnect";}

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE,                &mysql_local_infile)){*logstream <<"mysql option error local_infile";}

if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE,                  NULL)){*logstream<<"mysql option error MYSQL_OPT_NAMED_PIPE";}
if (mysql_options(conn,MYSQL_OPT_PROTOCOL,            (char *)&protocol))          {*logstream<<"mysql option error protocol";}

if (!mysql_real_connect(conn,
        "localhost", // SERVER
        "root",      // USER
        NULL,   // PASS
        NULL,   // DATABASE
        0,    // port
        NULL, // socket
        0     // client_flag
    )){
    *logstream<<"Database::connect mysql_real_connect failed"<<endl;
    *logstream<<mysql_error(conn)<<endl;
    conn=NULL;
}
```

The result of this mysql_real_connect call is:

```
Database::connect mysql_real_connect failed
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

If I use the TCPIP connection, everything works fine except that the Windows firewall pops up.  I would really like to make this work without requiring the user to click cancel on the firewall window.

Any help is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySQL is intentionally local only, you should simply configure it to listen only on the local address. Put this in your `my.cnf` file:

```
bind-address     = 127.0.0.1
```

Otherwise use `netsh advfirewall` or similar to configure the firewall to allow MySQL. This would generally be done when you install MySQL.

Examples:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Or from script:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845(v=WS.10).aspx

For a single-use installation which doesn't have or require admin privileges, you can configure local communication using the nonroutable IP address and a random port.

You can achieve this by adding `--bind-address=127.0.0.1 --port=62190` to the command line.

You won't be able to alter the firewall rules unless you are an administrator, and listening on named pipes generally requires administrative privileges too. Creating a shared memory section requires SeCreateGlobalPrivilege, so essentially the same restriction applies.

Comment: The netsh solution won't work because the program will not have administrator pridiledges.  The bind-address works quite well.  Although I'm still hoping someone answers explaining why the named-pipes won't work.  Thanks for the quick solution!

Comment: This is a portable mysqld executable.  There is no install process.

Comment: "This is a portable mysqld executable" That's vital information and should have been in the question! Listening on a named pipe requires admin privileges just as does changing the firewall.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem even with an admin-run mysql server in the current C connector 6.0.2
The bug was reported here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41860
I need to find a version of mysql C connector which doesn't have it.